# Adaptive Payment Partial Refund Functionality

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained-payments

I am sending the request like below and getting error in response. Please help me what I did wrong. Thanks .
My Request :- 
requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US
&requestEnvelope.detailLevel=ReturnAll
&payKey=AP-0VR709562K128704J
&receiverList.receiver(0).email=buyer@abc.com
&receiverList.receiver(0).amount=14.00
¤cyCode=GBP
My Response :-

```
Array
(
    [responseEnvelope.timestamp] => 2017-02-24T05:50:55.589-08:00
    [responseEnvelope.ack] => Failure
    [responseEnvelope.correlationId] => 66bf1bad1aa91
    [responseEnvelope.build] => 30051544
    [error(0).errorId] => 589037
    [error(0).domain] => PLATFORM
    [error(0).subdomain] => Application
    [error(0).severity] => Error
    [error(0).category] => Application
    [error(0).message] => The refund's receiver buyer@abc.com wasn't part of the payment request
    [error(0).parameter(0)] => buyer@abc.com
)
```

Comment: Please Help me in this issue. I am very needy for the solution.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution for this. In request We need to send receiver (seller) email not buyer email and it will automatically send refund to the appropriate receiver.

So the answer will be

```
requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US
&requestEnvelope.detailLevel=ReturnAll
&payKey=AP-0VR709562K128704J
&receiverList.receiver(0).email=api_email@apiemail.com
&receiverList.receiver(0).amount=14.00
¤cyCode=GBP
```

and we will get the responce like

```
Array
(
    [responseEnvelope.timestamp] => 2017-04-05T07:34:25.622-07:00
    [responseEnvelope.ack] => Success
    [responseEnvelope.correlationId] => 3a31df57541f3
    [responseEnvelope.build] => 31096492
    [currencyCode] => GBP
    [refundInfoList.refundInfo(0).receiver.amount] => 19.02
    [refundInfoList.refundInfo(0).receiver.email] => api_email@apiemail.com
    [refundInfoList.refundInfo(0).refundStatus] => REFUNDED
    [refundInfoList.refundInfo(0).refundNetAmount] => 18.37
    [refundInfoList.refundInfo(0).refundFeeAmount] => 0.65
    [refundInfoList.refundInfo(0).refundGrossAmount] => 19.02
    [refundInfoList.refundInfo(0).totalOfAllRefunds] => 39.04
    [refundInfoList.refundInfo(0).refundHasBecomeFull] => false
    [refundInfoList.refundInfo(0).encryptedRefundTransactionId] => 00487139PD976194Y
    [refundInfoList.refundInfo(0).refundTransactionStatus] => COMPLETED
)
```